# JQuery does not work in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui, dialog

I made a simple application to show a dialog with jQueryUI in VS 2008. This succeeded. When I try the same in VS 2010 nothing happens. It seems that ASP cannot get the jQuery library because when I do the following, no alert is shown when button `dialog_link` is pressed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Dialog Link
        $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
            alert("hello");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I put the following two lines within `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you imported the library?

Comment: Can you post the relevant rendered HTML (the bit with your button)?

Answer (score 2):

How does the rendered HTML look? I suspect, the html IDs are differing from VS2008 to VS2010.

From http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx:

> ASP.NET 4 supports a new ClientIDMode
>   property on the Control base class. 
>   The ClientIDMode property indicates
>   how controls should generate client ID
>   values when they render.  The
>   ClientIDMode property supports four
>   possible values:
>
> - AutoID—Renders the output as in .NET
>     3.5 (auto-generated IDs which will still render prefixes like ctrl00 for
>     compatibility)
> - Predictable (Default)—
>     Trims any “ctl00” ID string and if a
>     list/container control concatenates
>     child ids (example:
>     id=”ParentControl_ChildControl”)
> - Static—Hands over full ID naming
>     control to the developer – whatever
>     they set as the ID of the control is
>     what is rendered (example:
>     id=”JustMyId”)
> - Inherit—Tells the
>     control to defer to the naming
>     behavior mode of the parent container
>     control

Answer (score 0):

Working just fine, here is a live sample on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wh4PU/

100% the problem will be in the include tag of the jQuery file, can you post your script tags as well ?

**Update:** I'm suspecting that the file is not included, can you use the following script tags and try again?:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Thank you everybody. I can't use http links in src attribute because and don't have internet in my workarea. I've included the JQuery scripts in VS 2010 just dragging onto it.

Comment: It seems it already works. I closed the script tag with /> not with </script>